# What is nsComment in openssl?

Tags: openssl, config

What is `nsComment` in the config file in OpenSSL?
Eg. `nsComment = "OpenSSL Generated Client Certificate"`
And how to use it in OpenSSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man5/x509v3_config.html):

> The following extensions are non standard, Netscape specific and
> largely obsolete. Their use in new applications is discouraged.
>
> **Netscape String extensions.**
>
> Netscape Comment (**nsComment**) is a string extension containing a
> comment which will be displayed when the certificate is viewed in some
> browsers.

Comment: Is there any browser that can view the comment?